# How can I raise an error if my factory fails validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

If I use FactoryBot to create a record, but it fails validation, it only returns an unsaved instance. **Is there a way to make FactoryBot throw an error to help me debug issues early?**

```
FactoryBot.create(:house, some_options)
=> #<House id: nil, ...>
```

The test will continue and will ultimately fail somewhere else because my object was not valid.

My first thought would be to create a trait and somehow default it to all factories, but I'm not seeing an easy way to do that.

```
trait :ensure_validity do
  before(:create) do |obj|
    raise StandardError unless obj.valid?
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think Factories should throw errors, rather your test code should do that.. And if you have validations set up in actual models, then you will get errors already by Rails.. Anyway check [lint](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#linting-factories).

Comment: Have you tried `create!` instead of `create`? That's sort of the whole point of the `bang`.

Comment: @jvillian I should have mentioned that, I apologize. FactoryBot doesn't have a `create!` method.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Thanks for the suggestion! I'm not sure lint is the approach we want to take. Yes, a Factory itself may be valid, but the arguments that I pass to it may no longer make the resulting object valid. We do have validations setup in our models, Rails isn't throwing an error. Rails just doesn't save the object due to the validations and it's easy to miss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the "bang" version of methods.

```
house = FactoryBot.build(:house, options_hash)
house.save!
```

Unfortunately, `FactoryBot` doesn't come with a `create!` method, but ActiveRecord does.

In Rails, you can cause `ActiveRecord` to throw errors when a record is invalid by using the `:create!` method instead of just the `:create` method.

You could do

```
House.create!(FactoryBot.attributes_for(:house, options_hash))
```

Comment: That's a really interesting workaround! I was ultimately hoping for a way to quickly make this change across the entire code base, that change is a bit more complicated. I wonder if there's a way to make a patch to FactoryBot to achieve the same results. I tried poking around their code, but no such luck yet.

Answer (score 6):

factory_bot uses `save!` as the default for creating instances ([here is the configuration on Github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/af50afcfeff4c489ba41d101e00cba674e7f1fdc/lib/factory_bot/configuration.rb#L18)), so you should get an error right away if there are any validation errors. Are you by any chance using a custom `to_create` in your factory? Are you able to provide the complete factory?

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer.

Comment: In case you're interested: it's still applicable to the latest FactoryBot version, you can [check source code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/893eb67bbbde9d7f482852cc5133b4ab57e34b97/lib/factory_bot/configuration.rb#L22)

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the [callbacks](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks) to validate before persisting?

```rb
after(:build) { |record| raise 'foo' unless record.valid? }
```